# API documentation on InsightExternalData and InsightExternalDataPart REST APis

Tags: einstein-analytics

Is there any specific reason why InsightExternalData and InsightExternalDataPart REST APIs  is not documented in any of the official Salesforce documentation?

Regards,
Pradeep